# Unstable remix compiler error "Unknown exception during compilation"

Tags: compiler-errors, ethereum, compiler-warnings, solidity, remix

The Remix online compiler gives unstable error message between the same codes and similar scenario.

Remix keeps throwing "Unknown exception during compilation."
when the function is doing multiple dynamic returns( three uint[] dynamic array).

But when I size the returning to TWO dynamic arrays, the issue disappeared.
And now I have no any clue about the reason behind it. Have switch different pragma solidity version already.

//Remix throws Unknown exception during compilation.

```
function Determine_Result(uint GameId, uint RoundId) internal returns (uint[] memory WinnerUserId, uint[] memory DrawUserId, uint[] memory LoserUserId) {

    uint[] memory Im_WinnerUserIdSet;
    uint[] memory Im_DrawIdSet;
    uint[] memory Im_LoserIdSet;

    /*
    ...        
    */

    return (Im_WinnerUserIdSet, Im_DrawIdSet, Im_LoserIdSet);
}
```

//However, this works!? :(

```
function Determine_Result(uint GameId, uint RoundId) internal returns (uint[] memory WinnerUserId, uint[] memory DrawUserId) {

    uint[] memory Im_WinnerUserIdSet;
    uint[] memory Im_DrawIdSet;
    uint[] memory Im_LoserIdSet;

    /*
    ...        
    */       
    return (Im_WinnerUserIdSet, Im_DrawIdSet);
}
```

Is this a particular issue? What is the principle behind and how to solve this

Please, I am trapped by this for day

[image]

[image]

Comment: To my untrained eye this looks like a bug in the compiler.

Comment: oops, I will size the photo next time. thank for your kindly remind.

Comment: My point was that even though I do not know anything about Remix, If my compiler started to crash spuriously I would suspect that there is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: I see, so I may have to try other compilers if insisting to do thing by this way.

Comment: Yes, and if you have alternative compilers available it can also be a good idea to try them even if you end up solving the problem differently.

Answer (score 1):

Editing your function in the following way fixed the error you are receiving for me.

```
    pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract Test {
    function Determine_Result() public pure returns (uint[] memory WinnerUserId, uint[] memory DrawUserId, uint[] memory LoserUserId) {

        uint[] memory Im_WinnerUserIdSet;
        uint[] memory Im_DrawIdSet;
        uint[] memory Im_LoserIdSet;

        /*
        ...        
        */

        return (Im_WinnerUserIdSet, Im_DrawIdSet, Im_LoserIdSet);
    }

}
```

Your problem seems to have something to do with the compiler version. The code I wrote compiles down on version 0.5.2. The code you wrote compiles at version 0.4.22 but not on 0.5.2.

Far as I can see this is the result of you declaring 2 params you are not using inside your function.

It still seems like a bug in the compiler though that it errors in one scenario but not the other, at least now you know what is causing it.